# Почему самостоятельно переопределяется значение enum во viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Весь код написан на C#, WPF

Есть такой тип:

```
public enum Week
{
    Mon,
    Tue,
    Wed,
    Thu,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
}
```

Форма:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Понедельник" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mon, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Вторник" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Tue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Среда" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Wed, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Четверг" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Thu, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Пятница" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fri, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Суббота" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Sat, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="Воскресенье" IsChecked="{Binding WeekValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Sun, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <Button Content="Min" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Max" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Конвертер:

```
class EnumBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

        return parameterValue.Equals(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
    }
}
```

Свойство:

```
    private Week _weekValue = Week.Mon;
    public Week WeekValue
    {
        get => _weekValue;
        set
        {
            if (_weekValue == value) return;
            _weekValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WeekValue));
        }
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Max" значение "WeekValue" программно меняется на "Week.Sun". На форме тоже происходят изменения.

После этого, при нажатии на кнопку "Min" значение "WeekValue" программно меняется на "Week.Mon". Однако на форме ничего не происходит.

При дебагинге выясняется, что значение "WeekValue" меняется на "Week.Mon", но тут же происходит ещё одно переопределение значения, в предыдущее состояние ("Week.Mon" => "Week.Sun"). В итоге получается, что я не могу полноценно менять значение "WeekValue" для отображения на форме.

Я не могу понять, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Прошу помочь тех, кто может объяснить почему так работает и что мне надо исправить.

**Update**

Код обработчиков событий по кнопкам:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //min
        WeekValue = Week.Mon;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //max
        WeekValue = Week.Sun;
    }
```

Comment: Почему ComboBox не использовать?

Comment: А есть код события нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Недели сделаны для примера. В оригинальной программе используется enum c 3-мя значениями: Min, Avg, Max. И мне надо это реализовать в виде RadioButton.

Comment: @test123, добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в методе `ConvertBack` конвертера не используете значение `value`, при смене `WeekValue` ваш конвертер срабатывает последовательно для всех `RadioButton`. Ну и, естественно, последний в разметке стоит `Sun`, он и будет установлен.

Перепишите последнюю строчку примерно так:

```
return (bool)value ? Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString) : Binding.DoNothing;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Это помогло.